# Save image from iPhone camera directly to documents folder and not to camera roll?

Tags: iphone, camera

I am trying to figure out how to take a image with the iPhone camera and save it directly to the apps document folder, and if possible not in the camera roll.

I have my app showing the camera, and I can save the image to the camera roll, but I want to save it directly to the apps document folder.

Any idea ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what's this Storepath ? is this some pre-defined funct or we have to give this and if we have to give path to this then how ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try doing this in your `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` method:

```
UIImage *pickedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"imageName.png"];

NSError * error = nil;
[imageData writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    return;
}
```

Let me know if that works for you.